# hide element on click hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to toggle the class 'show' on the `ul` so that it shows/hides the menu but my JQuery is not very good and I can't seem to get it to work

```
 <nav>
   <ul class="show">
     <li><a href="#sec01">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec02">how it works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sec03">comments</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="hamburger"></div>
nav {position:relative; z-index:999; display:flex; height:70px; width:100%; background:none; @include centerer; font-weight:bold;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
@include small{background:#DADADA;}
@include xs {background:#DADADA;;}}
nav ul {display:flex; list-style:none; flex-direction:row;
    @include small{margin-top:160px;flex-direction:column;}
    @include xs{flex-direction:column;}}
nav li { padding:20px; text-transform: uppercase; 

    @include small{background:#fff; color:#000}
    @include xs{background:#fff; color:#000;}}
nav li:hover a {border-bottom:2px solid #ff0000;}

nav a,nav a:visited {  color:#fff;text-decoration: none;}
nav a:hover,nav a:active {color:#fff;   text-decoration: none; ; }
.show{
visibility:hidden;
}
.hamburger{position:absolute; z-index:999;top:10px; right:10px; height:50px; width:70px; background:#000;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hsaw3frL/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".hamburger" ).click(function() {
  $('ul' ).toggleClass( "show" );
});
});
```

Comment: Class selectors are preceded by a dot as in `.c-hamburger`. jquery has very nice documentation https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I am confused as to what click function you are trying to bind to.

Comment: @Learning2Code it looks like he is binding to a `div`.

Comment: In your fiddle the javascript settings (the gear icon) is not including jQuery — the "FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS" field says _"No-Library (pure JS)"_ so nothing will work. Fix that, you then have to change your JS so the selector is `.hamburger` not `c-hamburger`, and change `$('this')` to `$('ul')` ... which, after both your question and Caelan's answer were edited, both now do.  Your question now asks "what's wrong with this" about code that is correct, making the question moot. You should either restore your bad code in the question, since that _was_ the problem, or delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a lot of ways to achieve what you are trying.

fix selection of class , add new css property `.hide` , fix/update the `ul` element by giving it an id (you don't want to hide all `ul` elements)

html

```
 <ul id='menubar' class="show">
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hamburger").click(function() { 
    $('#menubar').toggleClass("hide");//toggle this class
  });
});
```

css

```
.hide{
display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: thats because jquery is not loaded. try the JAVASCRIPT setting and change framework and extensions to jquery

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hamburger").click(function() {
        $("ul").toggleClass("show");
    });
})
```

Comment: also doesn't seem to work on my fiddle unless i'm missing something

Comment: @tomharrison, try the updated version. Although I couldn't seem to find a `c-hamburger` element?

Comment: sorry should be just hamburger have edited it now to reflect this